# SignalR getting disconnected while applying Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am new to **SignalR** and building a live chat by using .**NET 5 and angular 13**. While establishing the connection it is giving this error-- Connection closed with an error. **NullReferenceException**

[image]

After multiple debagging I found out what is the root cause of the problem. When I inject any dependency to my message hub. NullReferenceException error is happened. without dependency the connection is established properly.

here is my MessageHub.cs code (with dependency)

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IMessageRepository _messageRepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public MessageHub(IMessageRepository messageRepository, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _messageRepository = messageRepository;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();

        var otherUser = httpContext.Request.Query["user"].ToString();

        var groupName = GetGroupName(Context.User.GetUsername(), otherUser);

        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

}
```

Startup.cs (ConfigureServices)

```
   services.AddSignalR(e=>
        {
            e.EnableDetailedErrors = true;               
        });
```

Startup.cs (Configure)

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("hubs/message");
        });
```

I extremely need this dependency to complete my functionality. I got stack with this. If I remove the **Dependency** it works fine. I tried to find some solution from various sources but didn't work for me. if anyone help me. I will be really appreciate for this.

Comment: So how do you register the service? Did you register it like the official doc do:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection#simple-dependency-injection-in-signalr?

Comment: I m using .NET 5,  this document doesn't work for .NET Core and above. But A solution I Applied that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some study, a solution I applied that worked for me. We Can Retrieve service object. so in startup.cs what I did given below

**Startup.cs (ConfigureServices)**

```
  //we can retrieve service object
  public static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
  
  services.AddSignalR()
  services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
  services.AddScoped<IMessageRepository, MessageRepository>();
```

In my MessageHub.cs instead of using Dependency Injection I Retrieve Required Service and define it in the filed like below

**MessageHub.cs**

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IMessageRepository _messageRepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public MessageHub()
    {
        _messageRepository = (IMessageRepository)Startup.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(IMessageRepository));
        _userRepository = (IUserRepository)Startup.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(IUserRepository));
    }

    // other code....
}
```

It worked for me. Now I can implement my necessary method from IRepository and SignalR also working properly.

Comment: The older code you had was better. This is the opposite of what you're supposed to do in most cases. You want the dependency injection system to pass the arguments into the hub. If that isn't working, then this should also not work.

Comment: @davidfowl mind elaborating on that? Remember this is asp.net on .net 4.X.

Comment: This code isn't ASP.NET Core?